# Checking whether JLabel's Icon is a particular Icon or not

Tags: java, icons, jlabel

I have this code:

```
if(seatE1.getIcon() == particular icon)
{
    // do something
}
```

I don't know what to write in `particular icon`. Should I write the path of the icon I want or what? If there is a better way to do it please let me know.

Comment: The best design would probably be to keep a separate model that stores the state.  It seems you are trying to use the View as the Model.

Comment: sorry but i didn't really get what do you mean by that, can you explain more plz

Comment: Sorry about that, what i didn't understand is what do you mean by saying "keeping a separate model that stores the state"

Comment: See [Java SE Application Design With MVC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is when you instantiate an imageIcon, put the filename as the description and then do toString(), which returns the description. Here's an example:

```
private final String IMAGEPATH = "image.png";
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(IMAGEPATH, IMAGEPATH));

if(label.getIcon().toString() == "image.png")
{
  //do something
}
```

That's one basic way of doing it, or you could make a class that extends ImageIcon and in the constructor assign the file path to a variable and make a method like getPath() which returns that variable.

(I haven't tested that code exactly, but I've used essentially the same thing in one of my programs before and it worked)